# Get last record of a day using joins in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table of data given timestamps and a couple of values where I want to get the last value of each day.

In raw SQL I would do it like this:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', a1.created_at) AS created_at,
       a1.my_value
FROM my_table a1
JOIN
  (SELECT max(id) AS MAX
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d', created_at)) a2 ON a1.id = a2.MAX;
```

I am working on a Flask Application where I want to use the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension and not *sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session* or raw SQL. The defined Model looks like this:

```
class MyModel(SurrogatePK, Model):
  __tablename__ = 'my_table'
  id = Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
  created_at = Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
  my_value = Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)
```

What I have so far is:

Outer query:

```
MyModel.query.with_entities(MyModel.created_at, MyModel.my_value)...
```

Inner query:

```
MyModel.query.with_entities(func.max(MyModel.id).label('max')).group_by(func.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', MyModel.created_at))
```

But I cannot find the way to join both together to get the desired result.

Comment: since queries come back as a list with flasksqlalchemy, can you do `MyModel.query.filter_by(created_at=datetime(year, month, day)).order_by(desc(created_at))[0]` ? I might have read your question wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't this just give me one record as opposed to a couple of records? What I want is a set of records consisting of the last record of each day (cf. sql query).

Answer (score -1):

This is how i would do it in sqlalchemy,

```
from sqlalchemy import literal_column

a2 = session.query(func.max(mytable.id).label("MAX"))
     .group_by(func.convert(literal_column('DATE'), mytable.created_at)).subquery()

session.query(func.convert(literal_column('DATE'),
              mytable.created_at).label("created_at"),
              my_table.my_value).join(a2, my_table.id==a2.c.id)
```